# Evaluating a double integral which Fubini's theorem doesn't hold

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to show that if $f(x,y))=\frac{(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ when $x,y$ not equal to$ 0 $ and $f(0,0)=0

$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \quad f(x,y) dxdy= -\pi/4$ and

$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \quad f(x,y) dydx= \pi/4 $

But I don't know how to evaluate these integrals,

I tired polar coordinates but that doesn't seem to work.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the substitution $x=y\tan(\phi)$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx&=-\int_0^{\arctan(1/y)}\frac{\cos(2\phi)}{y}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-\frac{\sin(2\arctan(1/y))}{2y}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{y^2+1}
\end{align}$$

and with the substitution $y=x\tan(\phi)$ we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy&=\int_0^{\arctan(1/x)}\frac{\cos(2\phi)}{x}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac{\sin(2\arctan(1/x))}{2x}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{x^2+1}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the iterated integrals are of opposite sign.

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $x=yu$ for the first integral we get

$$\int_0^1\int^1_0 \frac{y^2u^2-y^2}{(y^2 + y^2u^2)^2}ydudy$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{1}{y}\int^1_0 \frac{u^2-1}{(1 + u^2)^2}dudy$$
You can use partial fraction decomposition to evaluate this. You could have used partial fraction decomposition on the earlier integral too, but it's easier to see like this.